# How to tell if i am on Amazon Aurora mysql DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, amazon-aurora

After connecting to mysql instance of Amazon Aurora, i am trying to run some kind of query to tell me that i am on Aurora mysql.

I want to achieve this after connecting to db instance and at the db command line.

My intention is to run a query that specifically tell me that it is an aurora mysql versus say my own hosted db like Maria DB. I will use this to automate and prevent certain commands from running if it is not Aurora DB.

Comment: Amazon Aurora has a few special tables and variables. Checking for variables named `aurora` and seeing whether the `information_schema.replica_host_status` table exists are a few ways to check this if the information does not show up in the output of `SELECT @@version`.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';`  From the commandline, use `mysql ... -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'"`

Comment: @RickJames Your suggestion yielded the following data (below in CSV format) which does not suggest anything that i can use to be certain that its aurora mysql
<code>
    Variable_name,Value
    innodb_version,5.7.21
    protocol_version,10
    slave_type_conversions,
    tls_version,"TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
    version,5.7.21-log
    version_comment,"MySQL Community Server (GPL)"
    version_compile_machine,x86_64
    version_compile_os,Linux
</code>

Comment: A better approach may be:  `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Aurora%';`.  Never mind.  There is a `VARIABLE` named `aurora_version`.  So, I am pretty sure that it is not Amazon Aurora.  In one sample, I see 5.6.10 matching aurora 1.11.

Comment: Answers of the "duplicate" question (which isn't about detecting Aurora specifically) actually took me 8 minutes of squinting before I found the actual answer:  `| aurora_version          | 2.08.2                       |`  in the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`